# Azure mobile services + thinktecture identityserver v3

Tags: azure-mobile-services, thinktecture-ident-server, openid-connect, identityserver3

I'm trying to figure out how to integrate the identity server with azure mobile services for use from mobile clients. I already have the id server up and working barebones with a test aspnet mvc website using it via the openidconnect middleware.

I haven't found much info on how to do this with mobile services and I'm not exactly sure what the overall flow is as far as what talks to what first. Is it that the mobile client should call the id server directly posting the username password and getting a token and then set that token on the mobile user then, when calls are made to azure mobile service the token is then validated on a back channel from the service to the id server? Or how should it work?

I have already read the custom authentication docs on azure and found some azure team blogs on the subject but it seems like they are already out dated. Is there a way to simply insert the same openidconnect middleware into the azure pipe?

I'm hoping to get this ironed out because I have a number of web+native mobile (Xamarin) projects on the horizon and this would be the identity foundation for all of them.

Comment: +1 I am interested in doing this exact situation as well. From what I've seen my best guess is to do custom JWT mangling on the mobile service side, but I'm not sure of best practices when doing that to not create some security hole.

Comment: Hey Paul, looks like you and I are the only ones interested in this. I have made some headway right or wrong it is working and I'm thinking security-wise it should be solid. Here is a link to my post over at the thinktecture github site https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v3/issues/434 hope this helps.